# Use of である in formal writing after volitional form

Tags: word-choice

I need to write a short abstract for research paper in Japanese, I used the desu/masu-kei, but thought about changing it to the formal writing style de aru form.

I get that である is used after nouns and adjectives and also verbs followed by の, however I have several sentences where I use "～たいと思っています" and "～したいのです”. Is it appropriate to use である after volitional that is ～たいのである？ And will ～たいと思っています just turn into a simple ～たいと思っている or must I change it into ～たいと思っているのである?

Answer (score 3):

So-called である form isn't what you should put である in the end of every sentence. である only replace copula だ/です (and its conjugations), and other endings just remain as plain form. So when you change your style into である form from です form, you'll do:

> したい**です** → したい
>   したいと思ってい**ます** → したいと思ってい**る**
>   したいの**です** → したいの**である**